# nuxt : nuxtServerInit called after a click on a nuxt-link

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using **Nuxt** (vue.js) in **SSR** mode and I don't understand why when I click on a **nuxt-link**, the serverInit function  of the store is called.

Here is an example of a nuxt-link in my default layout :

```
<div class="font-weight-thin caption">
          <nuxt-link class="myLinkMenu" to="/notifications">Notifications</nuxt-link>
        </div>
```

When I click on this link, I see the log message in the console corresponding to that :

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
    console.log("STORE / nuxtServerInit");
```

Is it normal ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that's normal. Why should the link reinitiate nuxt? That does not make any sense. https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action shows more about this action. The only thing I could think of, is that you only initiate nuxt after that click – which seems very weird to me. Do you see the console message corresponding to this action even before the click? (indicating that the init action is called twice?)

Comment: It's not normal, the lifecycle of Nuxt is like this : ```* Incoming Request
* nuxtServerInit
  Store action
* middleware
  1. nuxt.config.js
  2. matching layout
  3. matching page & children
* validate()
  Pages & children
* asyncData() & fetch()
  Pages & children
* Render
* Navigate
  <nuxt-link>
  (points back to middleware) ``` according to this issue https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2521 What nuxt version did you use ? can you link a repo to repdroduce the issue ?

Comment: I'm using Nuxt ˆ2.0.0 in my current project, I've nuxtServerInit that perform some api calls and populate the store, dispatching some actions. I've put a console log as your example, but i notice that nuxtServerInit function is called only one time as expected, also when navigation occurs through nuxt-link component. Which version of Nuxt? Have you tried to delete .nuxt, node-modules and package.lock with a new npm install?

Comment: do you see any messages on click about rehydration or about miss matching DOM nodes?

Comment: Most often you get such behavior when you have a hydration problem. A hydration happens when the Server rendered HTML is not identical as the one that Vue.js generates to make your App interactive. Like Bart mentioned this is a DOM nodes mismatch. If u check the console you should than see a message that tells you where the mismatch happens.. often it's a simple as a not closed HTML Tag or not valid HTML